# Eclipse: Ant script to export User Library/Libraries for project

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I am new to Java programming. I initially started with NetBeans but have moved to Eclipse given the advice from a friend.

In NetBeans, a pre-written ant build script for the project would generate a Project.jar file and place all required libraries/jars in a lib/ folder.

However, in Eclipse it appears that I need to write my own ant script.  I have written a few lines to generate the jar file:

`<target name="compile">
   <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
   <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="jars" debug="on"/>
</target>`

How do I write a command to copy all of the jars in my User Library to a ${build.dir}/lib/ folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Alternative question: Given my Java class files are stored in "src/" and a set of dependent .jar files are defined in my User Libraries, could someone please post an example build.xml script which compiles the src files to "./dist/Project.jar", copies the .jar files defined in the libraries to a "./dist/lib/" folder, and generates the necessary manifest file in the jar?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task

like so, with the appropriate include or exclude pattern

```
  <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib/">
    <fileset dir="src_dir">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>



 <copy todir="${build.dir}/lib/">
    <fileset dir="src_dir" excludes="**/*.java"/>
  </copy>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. In my Eclipse project I have a "src/" folder with all of my source code. I have also defined some User Libraries. For example, I have defined a User Library with the name Apache Commons which contains a few jar's which I use in my project (specifically commons lang and commons math).  What I want is a simple Ant script which will compile the "src" files into a Project.jar and also copy automatically to a "lib/" folder the user libraries (in this case commons-lang-2.6.jar and commons-math-2.6.jar).

Comment: yes - so you can do that by adding the `copy` bit of my post into the same `target` you already have, after the `javac`

Comment: Your solution appears to copy *.jar from the src directory to the lib folder.  However, the .jar files I wish to copy are not located in the src directory.  Instead, they are stored in various places on my machine and referenced in my User Library. For example, in the .classpath file there is a line reading `<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Apache Commons"/>`. It is the .jars in this user library which I wish to include in a dist/lib folder. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: I dont think ant reads classpathentry for the build, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073693/include-multiple-jars-with-classpathentry as well

Comment: I believe your comment above ("I dont think ant reads classpathentry") is the answer to my question. I have restructured my project files and am no longer placing my required jars in a User Library but now keeping them in a lib folder within my project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Java take the chance to have a look at [maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It is a build tool like ant with a lot of predefined 'goals' and a fully developed dependency (to other libraries) handling. You will find a [eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) which will be very useful.

Maven projects have a special [directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) which is kind of best practise and helpful for beginners. If you work on a maven project you can just use the command

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

as a console command (or eclipse run configuration) to copy your project dependencies (libraries) to the `<project>\target\dependency` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [ant4eclipse library](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) for ant based eclipse projects. When you use it, you can access eclipse workspace/project settings, and can iterate tought eclipse project class path in ant.

See the example code bellow:

```
<path id="ant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/ant4eclipse">
        <include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
<taskdef resource="net/sf/ant4eclipse/antlib.xml" />

<targetPlatform

<target name="copy_jars">
  <getEclipseClasspath workspace="${basedir}/.."
                       projectname="TestProject"
                       targetPlatformLocation="c:/eclipse"
                       property="classpath"
                       relative="false"
                       runtime="true"
                       pathseparator="#" />

  <!-- iterate over all classpath entries -->
  <foreach list="${classpath}" delimiter="#"
    target="copy_jar_file" param="classpath.entry" />
</target>

<target name="copy_jar_file">
  <!-- check if current is a .jar-file ... -->
  <if>
    <isfileselected file="${classpath.entry}">
      <filename name="**/*.jar" />
    </isfileselected>
    <then>
      <!-- copy the jar file to a destination directory -->
      <copy file="${classpath.entry}" tofile="${dest.dir}"/>
    </then>
  </if>
</target>
```

If you would like to use user libraries, you can define it by [userlibraries](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/node/42) command.